# $\triangle {ABC}$, maximize AY while Y is reflection of X over median, X is on circumcircle.

Tags: geometry

> Suppose that $\triangle {ABC}$ is a triangle with $AB=13, BC=14, CA=15$. Let M and N be the midpoints of AB and AC, and D is the foot of A-altitude. Point X is chosen on the circumcircle of $\triangle {DMN}$ such that if Y is the reflection of A in MN, the length AY is maximal among all possible choices of X. Calculate AX.

What does it mean by "Y is the reflection of A in MN"? Is Y on MN? Or Y is X reflected about MN, hence on the other side of MN? I don't think Y is on MN, otherwise, the maximum AY would just merge with AX when X is the same as N.

Comment: "Reflection in $MN$" and "Reflection about $MN$" are synonyms.

Comment: It seems to me that A is reflected in any point of *line segment* MN. For example, its reflection in N is C, in M is B. This is Y. But I don't see how this depends upon choice of X.

Comment: Y is the reflection of A about MN.

Comment: There must be a mistake in the text: as written, it is meaningless.